# Sub string detection performance?

Tags: java, regex, performance

I need to match a sub string, and I wonder which one is faster when it comes to matching RegEx?

```
if ( str.matches(".*hello.*") ) {
  ...
}
```

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( ".*hello.*" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( str );
if ( m.find() ) {
   ...
}
```

And if don't need a regEx, should I use 'contains' ?

```
if ( str.contains("hello") ) {
   ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why `match` in one and `find` in another?

Comment: Please don't use `find` with a regexp that starts and ends with `.*` - you don't need the `.*` with `find`.  And yes, if what you're seeking is just a `String`, you should absolutely use `contains`.

Comment: RegExe are only needed when looking for a **pattern**. if you want to find an exact substring there is no need of it, have in mind that RegEx are expensive.

Comment: If performance is really a concern, why don't you index the data?

Comment: @DavidWallace I am aware of the .*, it's just an example for the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `matches()` and using a `Matcher` are identical (matches() uses a Matcher in its implementation), using a Matcher can be faster if you cache and reuse the compiled `Pattern`. I did some rough testing and it improved performance (in my case) by 400% - the improvement depends on the regex, but there will always be sone improvement.

Although I haven't tested it, I would expect `contains()` to outperform any regex approach, because the algorithm is far simpler and you don't need regex for this situation.

---

Here are the results of 6 ways to test for a String containing a substring, with the target ("http") located at various places within a standard 60 character input:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| Code tested with "http" in the input  | µsec | µsec | µsec |
| at the following positions:           | start|   mid|absent|
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| input.startsWith("http")              |    6 |    6 |    6 |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| input.contains("http")                |    2 |   22 |   49 |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^http.*")|      |      |      |
| p.matcher(input).find()               |   90 |   88 |   86 |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http.*") |      |      |      |
| p.matcher(input).find()               |   84 |  145 |  181 |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| input.matches("^http.*")              |  745 |  346 |  340 |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| input.matches("http.*")               | 1663 | 1229 | 1034 |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
```

The two-line options are where a static pattern was compiled then reused.

Comment: Thank you for the insight regarding `matches` and `Matcher`, I was not aware of that :) Would you recommend to use `contains` twice to avoid this kind of match: `matches("^https*.*$")`? One for the 'http' and another for 'https'.

Answer (score 1):

They are more or less equivalent if you use `m.match()` in the second code snippet. `String.matches()` specs this :

> An invocation of this method of the form `str.matches(regex)` yields exactly the same result as the expression `Pattern.matches(regex, str)`

this in turn specifies:

> An invocation of this convenience method of the form
>
> ```
>  Pattern.matches(regex, input);
> ```
>
> behaves in exactly the same way as the expression
>
> ```
>  Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).matches()
> ```
>
> If a pattern is to be used multiple times, compiling it once and
>   reusing it will be more efficient than invoking this method each time.

So calling `String.matches(String)` in itself will not bring performance benefits, but storing a pattern (e.g. as a constant) and reusing it *does*.

---

If you use `find` then `matches` could be more efficient if the terms don't match early, as `find` may keep looking. But `find` and `matches` don't perform the same function, so comparison of performance is moot.

Comment: In other words, the right tool for the right job. "matches" if I just want to know if the pattern is present. "find" if I need to match and get groups.

Comment: Almost. matches if you want to match the full string, find if you want to find or detect the presence *within* the string. Only `String.matches` forgets the groups, underwater it simply uses `Pattern.matcher(String)` which does report back the groups, no matter if you call `matches()` or `find()` on the resulting `Matcher`.

Comment: So for `find`, you would almost get the same result for ".*hello.*" as for "hello", main difference being that the first one matches the *last* hello in the string (".*" reaches to the end, then with traceback "hello.*"  is found), just "hello" matches the first hello.